# I did a switch case program, where it does not execute switch case when I give the input

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
void booking() {           //globally declared function
    printf("please select the seats");
    printf("1A 2A 3A G");
}

int main() {                //Main function
    int n;
    clrscr();
    printf("\t\t\t Railway reservation system");
    printf("1.Booking");
    printf("2.Availability checking");
    printf("3.Cancellation");
    printf("4.Prpare chart");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    switch(n)  //when I give input as 1 switch case is not being executed
    {
    case 1:
        booking();  //after the input it should execute this global function.
        break;

    case 2:  
        break;

    case 3:
        break;

    case 4:
        break;
    }

    return n;
}
```

My Aim is when we give the input n it should execute the globally declared functions.After the input it is not getting in to the switch statement.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is really that you don't flush the output buffer when printing, so you don't see the message? Add a trailing newline to the outputs you print. Also try to step though the code in a debugger.

Comment: Unless you are running from a console window, the output window may have closed too quickly for you to see the result.

Comment: "works" for me, but the lack of newlines makes the output very difficult to read.

Comment: "is not getting in to the switch statement": did you verify that in a debugger? What happens instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Place

```
printf("Press any key to exit...");
while (!kbhit()) ;
```

Before `return` statement, and you will see console screen before it closes.

Comment: `kbhit` is non-standard, suggest `getchar` and the message "Press Enter to exit..."

Comment: @WeatherVane Don't forget the trailing newline in the string, or a call to `fflush`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: so is OP's `clrscr`, and he doesn't seem to mind.

Comment: Not my DV although I can see why.

Answer (score 0):

In fact switch-case is executed, but you're probably not able to see it as your program finishes quickly. Try executing it from command line or put something like this at the end:

```
do {
    printf("Press q to quit: ");
    user_in = getchar();
} while (user_in != 'q');
```

One more thing: put new line character ('\n') at the end of every line in your menu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works.....if am not wrong we are using switch case statement to avoid usage of functions right? .....

Comment: Not really, more instead of long if/else statements. You can put it in a function as well and it would be perfectly fine.